# Filter grouping in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation

i have a query which aggregates the data based on the given filters, which mentioned below.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "country": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "messages": "desc"
        }
      },
          "aggs": {
            "messages": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "count"
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "country": [
              "US", "FR"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "locale": [
              "en_US", "en_FR"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

this query was returning all the data for both countries having the locales(which i mentioned in the filter) data

like: US -> en_US, en_FR and FR -> en_US, en_FR.

now i want to get the data for **US -> en_US and FR -> en_FR** (this i need to frame in the Filters logic of query). and the aggregation also need to be happened accordingly(based on countries and filters)

for this i am struggling to find or frame the query in Elastic search.
any suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "country": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "messages": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "messages": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "country": "US"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "locale": "en_US"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "country": "FR"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "locale": "en_FR"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: working fine without any must fields, but when i specified time-range in the must field, it was ignoring the constraints mentioned in the should. is there anything will get the data with in the given range and also satisfying the constraints which were mentioned in the sholud filed

Comment: If you add must conditions, you also need to add `minimum_should_match: 1`. I've updated my answer, please have a look.